# GUIで画像を表示させ再描画させたい

Tags: ruby

Rubyで1つの画像を表示させ再描画したいです。
これは画像をただ表示するだけです。これを再描画させたいわけです。

```
require 'tk'

photo = TkPhotoImage.new(file: "ruby.jpg")
TkLabel.new do
    image photo
    pack
end

Tk.mainloop
```

シンプルなもので結構です。できれば手動で更新するのは避けたいです。
Tk、GTKなどでもOKです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'gtk3'

toplevel = Gtk::Window.new('background')
toplevel.show

img = Gtk::Image.new('background.jpg')
toplevel.add img
img.show

GLib::Timeout.add(1000) do
  img.destroy
  img = Gtk::Image.new('background.jpg')
  toplevel.add img
  img.show

  true
end

Gtk.main
```

timeout がなくてもライブラリが勝手に再描画するでしょうが、
質問は手動での再描画をご要望のように読めたので、無理矢理
再描画するようにしてみました。

Comment: Timeoutを使えばいいんですね！とても参考になりました！